# Dynamically Create a Modal for a Note Taker App

Tags: javascript, html, css, simplemodal

I am working on a simple note taking app using vanilla javascript. I am trying to have the program add the note with a modal that when clicked would show the text. With what I have so far it is adding the note below the input box and along with the modal button. When I click the modal button it does nothing the first click. On the second click the text and modal button disappear.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Note Tracker</title>
    
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.success {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
  border-left: 6px solid #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Note Tracker Web App</h1>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <label for="iNote">Input Note:</label><br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="inote" name="inote" rows="4" cols="50">
    </textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="btn" onclick="addNote()">Add Note</button>
    <br><br>
    <div id="noteList">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>

    </div>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

Javascript is the below that creates the note and then add it along with the modal

```
    function addNote(){
    
    var item = document.getElementById("inote").value
    var text = document.createTextNode(item)
    var newItem = document.createElement("P")
    newItem.appendChild(text)
    document.getElementById("noteList").appendChild(newItem)
    
    var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    x.id = "someId";
    //x.onclick ="modalOpen()";
    x.onclick = function(){
        var modal = document.getElementById("noteList");
        var btn = document.getElementById("someId");
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    };
    var t = document.createTextNode("Open Modal");
    x.appendChild(t);
    document.getElementById("noteList").appendChild(x); 
    var z = document.createElement("BR");
    document.getElementById("noteList").appendChild(z);

    var newElem = document.createElement("BR");
    document.getElementById("noteList").appendChild(newElem);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

on first time, you are just attach event listener of click, simply put x.onclick outside the function

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this one will help.

So we have the "note-list" to handle the list.
I create a modal element that can activate when we click on the "new note" button.

In here I play with opacity and z-index to show this modal. Can be better than this.

```js
const newNote = document.getElementById('new-note'),
  addNote = document.getElementById('add-note');
let myModal = document.getElementById('my-modal');
newNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  myModal.style.zIndex = 99;
  myModal.style.opacity = 1;
});

addNote.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let note = document.getElementById('note'),
    noteList = document.getElementById('note-list');

  if (note.value !== '') {
    let _el = document.createElement('li');
    _el.innerHTML = note.value;
    
    let _a = document.createElement('a');
    _a.innerHTML = 'delete';
    
    _el.appendChild(_a);
    noteList.appendChild(_el);
    note.value = '';
    myModal.style.zIndex = -1;
    myModal.style.opacity = 0;
    
    _a.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.target.parentNode.remove();
    });
  } else {
    alert('note can not empty');
  }
});
```

```css
#my-modal {
  width: 100%: height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.modal-wrapper {
  border-radius: .5rem;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-top: 20%;
}

ul {
display: block;
}

#note-list li {
display: block;
margin-bottom: .5rem;
border: 1px solid #efefef;
background: #f7f7f7;
border-radius: .5rem;
position: relative;
padding: 1rem;
width: 70%;
}

#note-list li a{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
background: tomato;
padding: 1rem;
color: #fff;
}


.modal-wrapper * {
  display: block;
  margin: .5rem auto;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>Note Taker App</h1>

<div class="note-wrapper">
  <ul id="note-list">
  </ul>
  <button id="new-note">New Note</button>
</div>

<div id="my-modal">
  <div class="modal-wrapper">
    <label for="note">Your Note</label>
    <input type="text" name="note" id="note">
    <button id="add-note">add note</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is a big help what would be the best way to delete the last comment posted.

Comment: You mean after we add a note? in that note-taker app? Can you helpt to vote my answer that answered your question? thanks

Comment: Yes after we add the note. Okay I will vote

Comment: please check the code, just added how to delete the note :)